# How to stop a text animation from moving the logo when the text appears

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am making a mental health website. on the homepage of the website I have chosen to make a text that is animated as opposed to being static, just to make the website more lively and appealing.

this is what it looks like when the text appears.

[image]

The horizontal overflow is hidden, so the logo on the side is out of the page because the text has stretched.

How can I fix this?

```js
// sets the interval for which the function will run, in this case 8 seconds, (8000)
setInterval(function() {
  // grab all elements with class 'sub-head' and stores it in the elems const. 
  const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-head')
  // loop through the found elements 
  elems.forEach(e => {
    // check if the element has a class 'inactive', if there is one, remove it
    if (e.classList.contains('inactive')) e.classList.remove('inactive')
    // if not, add it. This is how it creates a loop. 
    else e.classList.add('inactive');
  });
}, 8000)
```

```css
/* The animation text*/

.intro {
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.intro1 {
  animation: showup 7s;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: purple;
}

.intro2 {
  width: 0px;
  animation: reveal 7s infinite;
}

.inactive {
  display: none;
}

.sub-head {
  margin-left: -355px;
  animation: slidein 7s infinite;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

@keyframes showup {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: .4;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: .8;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0% {
    margin-left: -800px;
  }
  20% {
    margin-left: -800px;
  }
  35% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 0px;
  }
  30% {
    width: 800px;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 800px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="first-box">



  <div class="intro intro1">Welcome!</div>
  <div class="intro intro2">
    <span class="sub-head "> We care about you</span>
    <span class="sub-head inactive">becuase you matter</span>
    <!-- lol dramatic effect-->
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: Set the max-width of that div to some value?

Comment: which div are you meaning ?

Comment: the outer most one (first-box)

Comment: Have you tried a transform translate instead of altering the margin?

Comment: i tried max width and there is no difference because the width is set to 100% already

Comment: I havent tried the transform translate one either because i cannot risk losing the code

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was you're setting so much width that the image/logo will also be affected by the width that you have set.

SOLUTION:
Set a static width on your `.intro2` class for example 300px or reasonable width that will only fit your static content.

```
.intro2 {
 width: 300px;
 animation: reveal 7s infinite;
}
```

You can check on this pen https://codepen.io/Preygremmer15/pen/MWoJBzv